# Facebook Setting Page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to create a Setting page in iPhone.

If you used Facebook in iPhone. You see that when we click on the Setting button on the navigationBar, the main page just go to right, but not disappear, and Setting page comes up.

When we click on the setting button again, we go back to the main page.

Do you know how can I create this functionality in iPhone? I appreciate that you give me some tutorial links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can grab this [JTRevealSidebarDemo](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo) and personalize as per your requirement.

There are plenty of other demo available like,

[DDMenuController](https://github.com/devindoty/DDMenuController)

[ZUUIRevealController](https://github.com/pkluz/ZUUIRevealController)

Comment: Thanks for you help. the only thing is I couldn't run the first link (JTRevealSidebarDemo). I just took a short look. should I do anything special to run it?

Comment: Actually there are 4 targets available in project. So from Top left Select 3rd item `JTRevealSidebarDemo` than it will run.  Assuming you are running XCode 4.x

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) with good success. It's light (2 classes) and easy to implement.